# Entities cannot be tracked by more than one context, interferes with N-tier design

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a colleague who insists I develop ASP.Net MVC websites using an n tier data access layer and MVVM.

He has a background in Silverlight and WPF and I have attempted to create a solution but it is causing problems.

I created and DAL and logic layers (using generics):

Dal - containing a repository pattern that wraps up entity frame work.
Logic - pass through layer, no generic logic to apply currently.

I am still using the MVC pattern and am passing the Entity framework model to View unless the need additional properties or methods - in which case I create a view model and an interface to map between the two.

The n tier data access layer has locked the entity framework context at the bottom of the stack and the main problem I have that entities can't be tracked on more than one context. ({"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."})

I recently came across a problem where context coming up with this error despite my attempts despite to use models, interfaces, deep copying.

The issue here is this was the approach I was going to take to try and put a model in the DAL layer and map the data between entity framework entity and model.

I understand the underlying issue: that even though you dispose of a context it doesn't release the entities that were attached to it. Is there anyway to get this n tire data access approach to work with MVC? or am right this will never work and I should stick to using the entity framework context in the controller method (or underlying class implemented using dependency injection).

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot to unpack here.

1. If you are looking for an MVVM implementation, then you are going to want to look at something like knockout.js.  Or some other framework that is going to do declarative databinding in the client side.  there are a number of articles that you can read to understand this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/knockout

but let's start with the assumption that you aren't going down that road and want to stick with MVC.

2. I would stop passing entities to your views.  You are going to cause yourself endless grief.  Create a view model for each corresponding view.  you use of an interface seems like overkill.  You can project linq queries for your entities/repos right into the the view models.  you could also use something like Automapper to map from entity to view model. Appending some of your code to the questions might help.  And my view models tend to be pretty flat.  I don't see why you would need to perform deep copies of entity trees out to the view.  Those can be gotten latter using partial views or some other method.
   Now that you aren't sending entities out to the view, when you post information for updating, you are going to have to instatiate a new object for fetch the object you are looking to update from ef again.  make your changes and save.
3. To me that simplest implementation is the best. I would pass you context to the controller method (preferably using an IoC) and querying the context directy in the controller action and projecting directly into the view model.  If you've got a lot of shared code between controller actions, maybe move stuff into a service and then inject the service into the controller and inject the context into the service.  but i'd start with just injecting the context into the controller.

Comment: With regards to point 2, it is only in the create action that I pass from the view to the ef.

Comment: In the edit action I take the id of the ef model (used as the viewmodel) and get the record using ef. There are addition audit info (created, modified, deleted and by whom) fields that are used on the view are managed server side

Comment: Point taken, will use view models. The problem I have is when you doing some more complex then the normal scaffold MVC project actions. The interaction with the logic and DAL mean I have get additional database records to validate and process an action. these are on there own context, it gets closed and the entites are still attached

Comment: The choice to use a dal and logic means I have this problem and agree a simple using (context) would solve all my problems. Is there anyway to use a logic layer -> dal layer - entity framework and perform complex action with multiple get, updates and create on controller/service layer without having the problem of "{"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."}"?

Comment: you keep mentioning interactions with the DAL and logic.  If you are using EF, you are using an ORM and your are only interacting with your domain objects.  They "DAL" is abstracted away inside of EF.  Do your entities have any business logic or are you using an anemic domain model.

Comment: public virtual IEnumerable<E> All(params Expression<Func<E, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {
            return includeExpressions
              .Aggregate<Expression<Func<E, object>>, IQueryable<E>>
               (DbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression)).ToList();            
        }

Comment: `        public virtual IEnumerable<E> All(params Expression<Func<E, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {
            return includeExpressions
              .Aggregate<Expression<Func<E, object>>, IQueryable<E>>
               (DbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression)).ToList();            
        }`

Comment: Abstract Data access layer:

Comment: using (IRepository<T> db = new Repository<T, C>(context))
                {
                    return db.All();
                }

Comment: Implementation of abstract dal:

Comment: public override IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {            
            return Where(r => r.Deleted == null);
        }

Comment: public override T Create(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IRepository<T> db = new Repository<T, C>(context))
                {
                    entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
                    entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                    entity.ByWhom = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                    return db.Create(entity);
                }

Comment: from the on the there is a 'group dal object'         public IDataAccessLayer<Setting> Settings { get; private set; } and Settings = new AuditInfoDAL<Setting, AppsContext>();

Comment: and the logic layer above just passes these properties using an interface call IBusinessLogic (inherits from IDataaccesslayer with no additions)

Comment: This set up means I keep getting the An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker unless I create a shared context in the logic layer (pass it down) and implement the logic using a using statement. For this this look identical a using statement around the repository or context directly

Comment: My colleague creates (separately in every project) a entites, dal, business logic and his DAL method are GetUserName(string domainName), GetCompanies(), CreateEngineeringRecord(EngineeringEntity model, int vehicleKey) etc

Comment: the business logic above includes logic that validates data and call the methods indicated above which is then implemented into a service layer

Comment: This approach for creates is hard to maintain (lots of methods, interfaces and services to drill down through) compared to the basic CRUD methods I implement in the dal and repository. I am testing a shared application logic approach that uses basic CRUD calls to create complexe logic but really want to remove some the layers between me and the entity framework.